# MVC C# Complex Model Editing

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, post, model, edit

I'm trying to find a way to edit an entry in my database, my model is something like this:

```
public class ComplexModel {
public int id {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public List<Lines> FavoriteNumbers {get;set;}
}

public class Lines{
public int id {get ;set ;} 
public string FavoriteLetter {get;set;}
}
```

My view has this to list input boxes

```
@model MvcApplication.Models.ComplexModel
@using(BeginForm()){
<fieldset>
<legend>Enter your name</legend>
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Name)
</fieldset>
@foreach (var item in Model.FavoriteNumber)
            {       

              <fieldset>
                <legend>Favorite number:</legend>
                @Html.EditorFor(model=>item.FavoriteLetter)
              </fieldset>
            }
<input type="submit" value="Save">
}
```

Would it be possible to edit every line in ComplexModel this way?
I have tried to edit but in the controller it says that my list is empty/null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a foreach, use a for loop. It would look something like this:

```
@for (int i=0; i < Model.FavoriteNumbers.Count; i++)
        {       
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Favorite number:</legend>
            @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.FavoriteNumbers[i].FavoriteLetter)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.FavoriteNumbers[i].id)
          </fieldset>
        }
```

I added the HiddenFor with id to make sure something is posted for the item. Otherwise, if the data is posted and a field is left empty, the list will be broken off.

Comment: Foreach is not the problem and it offers better readabilty than a for loop. I can't see why would you suggest to change it. This problem is most likely caused by a simple typo just like platon said.

Comment: All list model binding examples I've seen have used a for loop, so I'm just used to doing it that way. I don't think you can reliably tell which Line was posted without an index. It may not matter in this example, but it could be relevant.

Comment: After a bit of testing, I'm inclined to say that it's not possible to do this with a foreach at all. Unless the list contains a simple type such as string, in which case you can use something like Html.TextBox("FavoriteNumbers", item.FavoriteLetter). Html.EditorFor won't work in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Model.FavoriteNumberS, not Model.FavoriteNumber...